# pulseaudio sink always suspended

Tags: pulseaudio

I am on Debian Pulseaudio 2.0-6.1. Up to now never had any issues with sound.

I made some experiments with remote sinks and now it seems pulse it totally messed up.

I have only one sink. When I restart pulseaudio pactl shows the sink as IDLE.
As soon as an application tries to output sound the state changes to SUSPENDED and stays that way. "pactl suspend-sink 0 0" does not change the state. I can only get it to IDLE by restarting pulse and the cycle starts again.

After a reboot the problem persists.

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried disabling [suspend-on-idle](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index62h3) in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`? I change this:

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

to this:

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
#load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

and then to restart it. There is [quite a lot of variation in how people do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15223/how-can-i-restart-pulseaudio-without-having-to-logout) but `killall pulseaudio` has always worked for me (it gets automatically started again).

Comment: It helps me to startup Asus Xonar Essense One.

Comment: This solution also solved my problem when vlc was reporting "connection refused" errors.

Comment: Is there a way to limit this to specific sinks, like the HDMI one? I only have issues with my AVR not recognizing when the audio starts again after a longer pause.

Comment: Thank you! In case anyone wants to automate this in an installation script: `sudo sed 's/load-module module-suspend-on-idle/#load-module module-suspend-on-idle/' /etc/pulse/default.pa -i`

Comment: Maybe anchor the regex to start of line to make it idempotent?

Comment: Awesome. This solved the problem I have where my monitor hisses at me all the time I'm not using sound.

Comment: Why isn't the default value working?

Comment: On my system (Manjaro) there was another config where I had to remove the load-module line: ~/.config/pulse/default.pa

Comment: I also had to restart the program playing audio after killing pulseaudio to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** When I installed `pipewire-pulse`, and it replaced `pulseaudio`, all the issues resolved.

**WHY:** In my case, `pulseaudio` was not working because I had both `pulseaudio`, `pipewire` and `wireplumber` installed and working.

I only installed `pulseaudio` manually. However, I also installed GSConnect, and after a system update it must have installed `pipewire` and `wireplumber` as its dependency.

Comment: pipewire-pulse also fixed `Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.` on boot after recent (2022-09) update of ArchLinux.

Comment: did you have to reboot or something else? Doing what `sam-brightman` suggested helped me while `pipewire-pulse` didn't.